# Docusign - Is it possible to have a signer without name?

Tags: docusignapi

We use embedded signing. After our client signed the document, one of our managers needs to sign the document too. What we want to show to our client is that the document is signed by our company, instead of a specific person. What is the best practice of this?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the company name in the recipient used for your manager. See the JSON extract below :

**However**, it would not reflect who exactly signed for your company as the manager name would not be explicit

```
{
    "signers": [{
        "name": "Your Company",
        "email": "Yourmanager@yourcompany.com",
        "recipientId": "1"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, best practice is that a signature represents a *person* not a *company* or entity. I don't recall ever seeing a document that's been *signed* by a *company*. If possible, you might consider changing the structure/wording of the underlying document such that it shows that the manager is signing *on behalf of* the company. For example (where *John Doe* is the name of the manager who's signing on behalf of the company and *Jane Doe* is the name of the client):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocuSign Signing Group which is same like email distribution list. Send an envelope to DS Signing group, all members of DS Signing group will receive an email to dign the envelope and whoever picks up envelope and complete the signing, his/her name eill be printed on the document and in the audit history.